# Difference of two files using SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, file, api, office365apis, comparison

How do I get the **diff** of *file1.csv* and *file2.csv* from SharePoint (maybe using API calls, if possible)?

**diff** : Compare the contents of file1 and file2 and produce the list of changes necessary to convert one file into the other.

Answer (score 2):

Finding differences between two csv files is not an OOB capability of SharePoint. SharePoint could host the files, and you could use JavaScript to read and compare the file contents.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but can you think another way of doing it, like a hack for it?
Like, say for example, SPQueries or AzureAD application/functional app or something of that sort.. 
really appreciate your help, Thanks.

Comment: another great possibility is importing both into sql (or Access), and running queries. Both tools were designed for this sort of thing.